# Zope register external methods using zcml configure

Tags: methods, external, configure, zope, zcml

Is it possible to register external methods for Zope using a configure.zcml file or something similar?  I'm trying to register external Python scripts (similar to other registry items such as "jsregistry.xml" or "cssregistry.xml" in themes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. External Methods are "old tech", pre-dating the Zope Component Architecture by several years.

You can easily add a GenericSetup import step that creates ExternalMethod objects on demand, but since only python modules located in the `Extensions` directories (inside Products and the `INSTANCE_HOME` location, you may as well just enumerate those locations via the usual Python file-access methods, add everything you find there and not use a registry at all.

However, are you absolutely certain you want to use an ExternalMethod? Wouldn't a simple utility or view be easier?

Comment: Could you point to more information/documentation for a utility or view?  It's very possible these would be easier...

Comment: Also, take a look at ZopeSkel. You can create a skeleton for an add-on with a view in seconds. Really *much* easier than an external method.